# How to create trigger which increment colum value after inserting the row?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a database in MySQL. Here is SQL query to create it http://paste.org.ru/?xzctqi

Here is main table `books`. All I need to do is when I add some book, I choose publisher ID for it. After adding books, I need loop through all records in this table and increment column `publisher_books_amount` for all rows, which has same publisher as in currently added row.

```
+----+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------+
| id | title | author | publisher_books_amount | publisher |
+----+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Book1 |      1 |                      0 |         1 |
|  2 | Book2 |      2 |                      0 |         1 |
|  3 | Book3 |      1 |                      0 |         2 |
|  4 | Book4 |      3 |                      0 |         3 |
|  5 | Book1 |      3 |                      0 |         1 |
+----+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------+
```

I've created trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_trigger`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON books
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE books SET publisher_books_amount = (publisher_books_amount + 1) 
        WHERE publisher = NEW.publisher;
    END;
    |
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I'm trying to add book, MySQL provides me with an error.

> Can't update table 'books' in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Don't ask me why do I have denormalized DB. I just need structure described above.

BTW I need to create same triggers after deleting and updating rows. If there are some problems with that, could you help me with it too?

Sincerely, Dmitriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update inside a loop is not allowed, because it goes to infinite loop.
Try your triiger without update,with only set value this=this.